# ksh read file names from a directory

Tags: ksh

I am writing a Korn Shell script that will take a zip file and unzip the contents to a directory.

The file may not always be in the directory and it will have the release date in the name e.g. `ALLIANCEBANK_DELTA_20141004_ABE.zip`.

I wrote a quick script to check for the file's existence replacing the date with `*` (`ALLIANCEBANK_DELTA_*_ABE.zip`).

If I echo the variable it expands the name, but the if statement is not expanding it.

```
#!/bin/ksh

ALLIANCE_BANKFILE=/swift0/usrdata/messages/FA_ALLIANCE_BANKFILE_OUT/ALLIANCEBANK_DELTA_*_ABE.zip
echo $ALLIANCE_BANKFILE
if [[ -e $ALLIANCE_BANKFILE ]]
then
    print "$ALLIANCE_BANKFILE found"
else
    print "$ALLIANCE_BANKFILE not found"
fi

running this gives me:

$ ./file-exists-test.ksh
/swift0/usrdata/messages/FA_ALLIANCE_BANKFILE_OUT/ALLIANCEBANK_DELTA_20141004_ABE.zip
/swift0/usrdata/messages/FA_ALLIANCE_BANKFILE_OUT/ALLIANCEBANK_DELTA_*_ABE.zip not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The expansion of the wildcard does **not** happen in the variable assignment. It does happen in the echo because the variable is not quoted.

If you have **ksh93**, you can do this: store the files names (there may be 0, 1 or more) in
an array. use the `~(N:pattern)` form so that if there are no files matching the pattern then the pattern is replaced by the empty string (default: if there are no matching files, the pattern string remains).

```
dir=/swift0/usrdata/messages/FA_ALLIANCE_BANKFILE_OUT
ALLIANCE_BANKFILES=( ~(N:$dir/ALLIANCEBANK_DELTA_*_ABE.zip) )  # use an array

if (( ${#ALLIANCE_BANKFILES[@]} == 0))
then
    print "no ALLIANCE_BANKFILES found"
else
    print "${#ALLIANCE_BANKFILES[@]} files found:"
    printf "%s\n" "${ALLIANCE_BANKFILES[@]}"
fi
```